# How to write own DLL in Visual Studio, C language (not C++)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, dll, compilation

I'm trying to create my own DLL... I used wizzard in VS2008 to create template for DLL. This works fine and the dll builds successfully (Test.dll is created).

BUT, when I rename the file from Test.cpp to Test.c (which I guess causes compilation in C-mode), solution rebuilds also successfully, but no .dll is created. The list of all created files follows:

```
mt.dep
BuildLog.htm
vc90.idb
Test.dll.embed.manifest
Test.dll.intermediate.manifest
Test.obj
MySecondCFile.obj
vc90.pdb
Test.dll.embed.manifest.res
```

For my purposes it's essential that the dll be in C not C++, while I already have a lot of code written in C, which does not compile as C++.

Do you know, why .dll is not created? What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this fixes your problem, but you should start with modifying your project to compile as C code and not as C++.

Right click on your project -> properties -> C/C++ -> advanced -> Compile as C code.

Comment: Already tried this. Did not help. Project builds, but no DLL file is created:
Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped

Comment: And if you delete your build result directories/do a full rebuild? You need to make sure you do a full rebuild to make sure your entire DLL is properly rebuilt.

Comment: Oh, I found that DLL! Some file were stored in SolutionName\ProjectName\Debug, but DLL was in SolutionName\Debug.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: SolutionName\ProjectName\Debug - precompilation result files go here
SolutionName\Debug - build result files go here
It's common and default for all VC++2008 projects.